# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community's issues are properly addressed.

[image: aeismail]
[image: eykanal]
[image: user102]
[image: F'x]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections after your site makes it through graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It's a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Excellent choices!

Comment: I think the edits to this question created a mess. They hide the fact that one of these moderators was added later and is not part of the original announcement, and they removed the name of one of the original moderators (now a deleted user). This question today has mostly "historical documentation" interest, and the edits completely hide it. Please take a look at the edit history if you *really* want to know who was appointed moderator pro tempore in 2012.

Comment: I would have notified @StrongBad and Shog9, but someone at SE decided that I cannot at-notify editors. Bad choice. :(

Comment: @FedericoPoloni the mod essentially changed his user name. The flair normally updates and reflects the current status and not the status at the time of appointment. I think that the user deleting his account screwed this up. The idea of the deletetion was to disassociate his name from his contributions. This seemed like an odd remnant. That said, I didn't purge the history and if you think my edit harms it, we can roll it back. I don't feel strongly about it.

Comment: @StrongBad Oh, so my message *did* at-notify you? Interesting. Then it's just the auto-completion that does not work with editor names, but the functionality works. Anyway, if it were for me I would just revert to Version 2 and cherry-pick the changes from Version 4, but I also don't feel strongly about it (as long as a comment stays to point out that there is more to this). All this assuming that there is no particular story unknown to me behind CM's account deletion --- I can understand trying to hide it if he asked for it explicitly.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, editors are notified, see [this faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/300001) on the main meta: "Any user who has edited the post (does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions)".

Comment: 1 of your images broke, and is returning a 500 error

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations to our new moderators!