# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Academia's [first moderator election](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 4 new moderators are:

[image: aeismail] [image: eykanal] [image: ff524] [image: StrongBad]

They'll be taking over for [the moderators pro tempore](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) shortly — please thank them *all* for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5161664651460608/0).

Comment: Congrats to all the new mods, and the old ones !

Comment: Congrats to the winners!

Comment: Congratulations and good luck to the new moderators, and thanks a lot to the old ones! :)

Comment: Fun fact: due to the election and following the removal of my diamond, I got awarded the [Marshal](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal) badge!

Comment: Congrats to all four of you!

Comment: Congratulations!  I've seen excellent comments and answers from all of you.

Answer (score 12):

Congratulations to the new mods, old and new school! Based on the answers provided in the [questionnaire](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/990/2014-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire), I have no doubt this new moderation team will be up to the task!

Good luck to deal with all the flags, thanks to all the runners for the interesting debate, and thanks to the whole community for voting!

Comment: Congratulations to all, this was a very active election and an additional occasion to discuss our moderation philosophy, which is always a good thing. Good luck to the new mod team!